# Вопрос про background-position

Tags: css

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть двойная картинка, то есть, для обычного показа и для псевдокласса hover. При наведении курсора мышки на картинку, он начинается плавно "переезжать" на второе изображение. Как можно сделать, чтобы он просто показывал вторую картинку? Самое странное, что, если взять другую картинку, например [эту](https://ru.wargaming.net/shop/static/2.0.12/common/css/scss/content/img/bg-menu-item.png), то все работает отлично (http://jsfiddle.net/Z3rnh/). Из-за чего может происходить такое? Может, нужно делать небольшой отступ от картинок?

```
    .button100 {
    display: block;
    width: 496px;
    height: 67px;
    background: url("../images/donate/100.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
.button100:hover {
    background-position: 0px -67px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

такое может происходить например из-за свойства transition

Вот смотрите: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3rnh/1/ — такой эффект?

Если да, то перебиваете это свойство например так:

```
transition: background-position 0s linear;
```

и всё будет как надо: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3rnh/3/

Comment: @Елена Левина, большое спасибо, решил!